# Custom user model auth form modification

Tags: python, django

I created own user model which is using e-mail as username and I decided to use own views for it. So I created the form for an user authentication. It works good, but there is one problem: it marks *input* type as **"text"** in HTML output, but I need it marked as **"email"**

I've tried to override **"__init__"** function with updating widget attributes, but it works only with "placeholder", "id" and other tags,
Modifying "username" didn't work as well

```
class CustomUserAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'type': 'email', 'placeholder': 'e-mail'})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'password'
```

```
self.username = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'type': 'email', 'placeholder': 'e-mail'}))
```

I want to get:

```
<input type="email" name="username" autofocus="" placeholder="e-mail" required="">
```

But I get:

```
<input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" placeholder="e-mail" required="">
```